# Agregar un "class" a un body sin postback usando ajax

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net

Estoy utilizando ajax y tengo un problema! cuando utilizo el ModalPopupExtender se muestra lo que quiero pero no puedo agregar una clase a un etiqueta, especificamente a la etiqueta "body"
tengo el siguiente codigo

```html
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head runat="server">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
</head>
<body id="css_body" runat="server">
  <form id="form1" runat="server">
  
    <ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender ID="mp1" runat="server" PopupControlID="Panel1" TargetControlID="btnInicial" CancelControlID="btnClose" BackgroundCssClass="modal-backdrop fade in"></ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender>
    
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager" runat="server" EnablePartialRendering="true" />
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
    
      <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="Show Modal Popup" OnClick="btnShow_Click" />
      </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>

    <asp:Button ID="btnInicial" runat="server" Text="Button" style="display:none" />

    <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server" CssClass="modalPopup" Style="display: none">
      <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel2" runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>

          <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>

        </ContentTemplate>
      </asp:UpdatePanel>

      <asp:Button ID="btnClose" runat="server" Text="Close" />
    </asp:Panel>


  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

cuando doy click al buton1 me muestra el label hasta cambia la propiedad "Text" sin postback pero la etiqueta que quiero cambiar no cambia tengo el siguiente codigo en lado del servidor

```c#
protected void btnShow_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "style", "document.getElementById('css_body').classList.add('modal-open');", true);

Label1.Text = "resultado";

mp1.Show();
}
```

como podria solucionarlo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deberías usar el [ScriptManager](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.scriptmanager(v=vs.110).aspx) en lugar de `Page.ClientScript`:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(
    this,
    GetType(),
    "style", 
    "document.getElementById('css_body').classList.add('modal-open');", 
    true);
```

Comment: intente de eso modo pero me sale el siguiente error  "CS1501 Ninguna sobrecarga para el método 'RegisterStartupScript' toma 4 argumentos "

Comment: @aldairguzmanbolaños perdón, ahi actualicé el ejemplo

Comment: muchas gracias me funciono correctamente!!!